# jQuery console logging image source not working $(this).find('img').attr('src');

Tags: jquery, html, find

I'm trying to console log an image source using $(this).find('img').attr('src');

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="stage">
        <div id="gallery">
            <img class="photo" src="_images/image#1" />
            <img class="photo" src="_images/image#2" />
            <img class="photo" src="_images/image#3" />
            <img class="photo" src="_images/image#4" />                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS

```
function grabIt(){
  var thisImageSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
}

console.log(thisImageSrc)

$('#gallery img').mouseover(grabIt);
```

I'll be using the img source within a larger function which is outside the scope of this question. My goal is to grab the image source when mousing over an image.

I'm new to jQuery and it would be easier for me to understand the long form of the answer code instead of functions nested inside of functions - if possible.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put the `console.log` statement **inside** the function. `thisImageSrc` doesn't exist outside of `grabIt` and `console.log` is called before `grabIt` has ever been executed.

Also, since you bind the event handler to the image itself, `$(this).find('img')` will return an empty set. An image cannot contain another image. Access the `src` property on the element itself.

So, fixing both things, you end up with

```
function grabIt(){
  var thisImageSrc = this.src;
  console.log(thisImageSrc)
}

$('#gallery img').mouseover(grabIt);
```

Comment: Thank you. While this does work, is $(this).find('img').attr('src') a longer way of writing that?

Comment: No. As I said, `this` refers to the `img` element. `$(this).find('img')` would try to find `img` elements *inside* the `img` element. But since that's not possible, it would return an empty set. Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/find/ to learn more about `.find` and https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ regarding event handling.